# Extract a decimal number from a string with jQuery where there are a bunch of other values

Tags: jquery, regex, decimal

I'm trying to extract a decimal number from a div (so inside a string) with jquery. My problem is that I can't use value (which could be ideal for me) so I have to deal with a string.

My other problem is that, inside my string, unfortunately, there are other numbers.

So I added a dollar sign in front of my number, so I can easily isolate it.

My array is the following (at this moment is just an option tag with some selections):

```
<select id="easypost" name="shipping_method">
    <option>
        Select shipping method...
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        Priority $38.565
    </option>
    <option value="1">
        ExpeditedParcel $19.56
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        RegularParcel $19.56
    </option>
    <option value="4">
        Xpresspost $24.66
    </option>
    <option value="5">
        PurolatorExpress9AM $84.855
    </option>
    <option value="6">
        PurolatorExpress1030AM $52.665
    </option>
    <option value="7">
        PurolatorExpress $32.175
    </option>
    <option value="8">
        PurolatorGround $31.605
    </option>
</select>
```

I'm doing some math with my result, but the important part is the variable double number.
I just need to extract the number right after the dollar sign I guess, but I'm open to gathering a better suggestion on this topic.

```
$('#easypost').change(function() {
    var shipping = $("#easypost option:selected").text();
    var doublenumber = Number(shipping.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
    var tax_per = ((doublenumber / 100) * 13).toFixed(2) / 1;
    var finaltotal = (totnumber + doublenumber + tax_per).toFixed(2) / 1;
    console.log(doublenumber + " " + tax_per + " " + finaltotal);
    $('.total').text(finaltotal);
}
```

My problem, as you can see, is when I try to extract the values from PurolatorExpress9AM $84.855 or PurolatorExpress1030AM $52.665.

Comment: If you are able to edit the markup, since you said you added the `$` to it, another option would be to put the money on the option as a data field.  Then you don't have to find it, just access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#easypost').on('input', function(){

  //version using the text
  //get the text and trim it
  var value = $('option:selected', this).text().trim();
  //ignore the first option
  if (value.indexOf('$') > -1) {
    //get all the text after the $ and parse it
    value = parseFloat(value.substr(value.indexOf('$') + 1));
    console.log(value);
  }
  
  
  
  //version using the data field
  var value2 = $('option:selected', this).data('cost');
  
  if (value2) {
    console.log(value2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="easypost" name="shipping_method">
  <option>
    Select shipping method...
  </option>
  <option value="2" data-cost="38.565">
    Priority $38.565
  </option>
  <option value="1" data-cost="19.56">
    ExpeditedParcel $19.56
  </option>
  <option value="3" data-cost="19.56">
    RegularParcel $19.56
  </option>
  <option value="4" data-cost="24.66">
    Xpresspost $24.66
  </option>
  <option value="5" data-cost="84.855">
    PurolatorExpress9AM $84.855
  </option>
  <option value="6" data-cost="52.665">
    PurolatorExpress1030AM $52.665
  </option>
  <option value="7" data-cost="32.175">
    PurolatorExpress $32.175
  </option>
  <option value="8" data-cost="31.605">
    PurolatorGround $31.605
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use split, this can help you

```
myArry = document.getElementById('easypost');
myArry.childNodes.forEach(function(ele){ 
txt = ele.textContent ;
txt = txt.split("$");
console.log(txt[1]);
})
```

the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfDI4.png)